# Globals lost when function calls itself

Tags: python, function, eval, local-variables, global

I need to add a variable "a" to global variables at runtime and be able to recover it anytime from the Item class. Result: I can't see it in the global variables.

Below there is an example. When I print the globals() I don't find the new "a" variable.

Specifically I need to be able to save the printVal result in a variable called "a", which I can consult in next call to this function.

In my final program I plan to add as many different variables as I want (variable and value).

Example:

```
class Item():
    def printVal(self,value):
        return value

    def func(self):
        userInput = input("Input string:")
        if userInput!="0":
            exec("a=self.printVal(\""+userInput+"\")",globals(),locals())
        else:
            return
        print(globals())
        self.func()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    item = Item()
    item.func()
```

Comment: What exactly is input? Just "a"? Better, make a test copy of this script and instead of inputtting something, have func take a value. Then `item.func("whatever the test is")`. Take `input` out of the equation and you have a concrete example without the added complication.

Comment: Just use `global a; a = <foo>` if you want to add `a` to globals

Comment: What is the idea of using `exec` here? Doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: This very much looks like XY problem. Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve. I suspect there is some confusion/lack of understanding how to work/use with class/OOP. Why the recursion call? Maybe you just need an instance attribute?

Comment: "func" would act as a menu, the user would input the variable and the function to call: e.g he would input "a < printVal" which has the form "{any_variable_name} < {existing_function_name}", meaning assign to variable "a" the value of call to "printVal". That's the reason I need to call exec. The parameter of printVal does not play any role here. It would serve me aswell to call printVal() and having this one return a given string.

Comment: I solved it by adding a class dict and having exec save data to this dict. Seems an optimal solution for my initial problem. If anyone wants to complete with a solution to the presented problem is fine. Otherwise I will delete this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you jus watn to set a global variable with a name generated at runtime you do:

```
globals()[name] = val
```

by the way `printVal` method is dummy. Just return whtat it gets.

Comment: I ended up with another approach, but this works and it's a very simple solution. Thanks!